# 人の物も in カードは人の物も使える

Tags: meaning

From *Liar Game* chapter 45, this guy got swindled to hand over money to enemy team and he explained why he did.

[image: 1]

> 秋山が言ってたじゃないか、カードは人の物も使えるって

I am not sure what「カードは人の物も使える」is supposed to mean. The fan translation suggests it means "Other people can use your (bank) card." The 人の物も part throws me off. What is the structure of this sentence? Surprisingly, a quick google search of this phrase seems to suggest that the translation is valid.

For bit more context, few chapters ago Akiyama explained to the team that there are many ways to use a bank card in game: players can not only withdraw money but also deposit money, players can use other player's card, and cards can be renewed if it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> カードは人の物も使える

I understand it as...

*lit.* Speaking of cards, (we/you) can use other people's (cards) as well.

人 here means "others" ie "other players".
The の is the genitive case (possession).
物 refers to カード.

A similar example from the web:

> 「クレジットカードはご家族のものでもかまいません。」

Comment: Thanks, it was too obvious...

Comment: Just to confirm, the example you just added means "Regarding credit cards, it is okay to use your family member’s card as your own"?

Comment: @Jimmy, そうそう、「クレジットカードで払うときは、家族のクレジットカードで払ってもいいですよ。」(When you pay by a credit card, it is okay to pay by your family member's credit card.) って意味です。